# Insert multiple annotated polygons in ggplot background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph using ggplot2, which I envisage as the combination between these two plots:

1. The one showing the growing season of each of my crops:
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1vx6.jpg)
2. The other showing the number of images per month for the three years of study: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKLDl.jpg)

In essence what I am going for is for the 1st image to be in the background and all the data to be in the front.

What I tried so far:

- using the first image as background to the ggplot.
- using `+ geom_poly()` or a fat `+ geom_segment()`

but wasn't able to make either one work as seamlessly as I would like it to.

The point data looks like this:

```
input2 <- read.table(
    text = "rowname key variable  value
    1    January     2016   8233
    2   February     2016  11573
    3      March     2016  23016
    4      April     2016  32029
    5        May     2016  51280
    6       June     2016  30652
    7       July     2016  62877
    8     August     2016  80680
    9  September     2016  60807
    10   October     2016  74004
    11  November     2016  60995
    12  December     2016  39608",
    header = T,
    stringsAsFactors = F)
```

My plot code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(input2, aes(x=key, y=value, color=variable))+
  geom_point(aes(size=value)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")) +
  #annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  #geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2, colour = "segment"), data = grass) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#CC6600", "#999999", "#FFCC33")) +
  ggtitle("Number of Images per month\n") +
  labs(x="Month",y="Number of images", fill="Legend")
```

The stuff commented out are my unsuccessful attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `geom_rect` and `geom_text` like this to get close to your ideal plot.

```
potato_season <- data.frame(
    crop = c("potato", "yam"),
    start = c("January", "March"),
    end = c("August", "October"),
    y_pos = c(20000, 24000)
)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(input2, aes(x=as.factor(key), y=value, color=as.factor(variable))) +

    geom_rect(data = potato_season, inherit.aes = F,
              aes(xmin = start, xmax = end,
                  ymin = y_pos - 2000, ymax = y_pos + 2000,
                  fill = crop)) +
    geom_text(data = potato_season, inherit.aes = F,
              aes(label = crop, y = y_pos, x = start),
              hjust = -1) + # to shift the text right

    geom_point(aes(size=value)) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("#CC6600", "#999999", "#FFCC33")) +
    ggtitle("Number of Images per month\n") +
    labs(x="Month",y="Number of images", fill="Legend")
```

[image]

Not sure what bumps you are referring to with the seemless-ness, but hopefully this helps. Let me know if you get stuck implementing it.

Comment: Great! Almost spot on! Was wondering whether you had a suggestion of how to incorporate the fact that growing seasons don't start at the onset of the new month or end at the end of the last, but sometimes do start and stop somewhere in the middle of a month. Thank you!

Comment: @Momchill The real way to do that would be to convert your data to class `Date` and graph on a date axis, which would let you specify any day of the month. The hacky way to do this would be to use decimal numbers (ggplot has to assign underlying numeric values to discrete axes, so January is 1, February is 2, and so on. Starting your rectangle at 1.5 would put the start halfway between the two).

Comment: @JanBoyer , thanks for the suggestions. I ended up using dates and this worked perfectly for split growing seasons as well.